# Camel K Demo is not running on Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I'm sorry but it's a newbie question, but I just can't figure the problem out. My Docker skills are quite beginner level.

I started with https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/2.0.x/index.html

and installed the `kamel` cli tool on my mac with apple chip.
The kamel tool works quite well.

After that I installed Camel K on Docker Desktop like described here (I also enabled kubernetes):
https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/2.0.x/installation/platform/docker-desktop.html

after that I wrote the groovy file:

```
from('timer:tick?period=3000')
  .setBody().constant('Hello world from Camel K')
  .to('log:info')
```

and executed `kamel run helloworld.groovy`. Kamel itself did not report any error and also `kamel logs` only showed

```
❯ kamel logs helloworld
Integration 'helloworld' is at: Error ...
```

So I took a look via `docker logs [containername]` and the first error log entry is this:

```
{"level":"error","ts":1697092933.5625799,"msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"integration-controller","controllerGroup":"camel.apache.org","controllerKind":"Integration","Integration":{"name":"helloworld","namespace":"default"},"namespace":"default","name":"helloworld","reconcileID":"44bb6dcd-26ee-453a-b9aa-7895fb5119df","error":"error during trait customization: unable to find integration container: helloworld","stacktrace":"sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n\tsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.13.1/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:326\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n\tsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.13.1/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:273\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func2.2\n\tsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.13.1/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:234"}
{"level":"info","ts":1697093266.9122443,"logger":"camel-k.cmd","msg":"v1apha1.KameletBinding is deprecated, please, use v1.Pipe instead\n"}
```

Why is there no integration container "unable to find integration container: helloworld"? Did I forget something to execute? I read the documentation over and over again, but I am not able to find the missing piece. Pls help.

Edit: I found those log lines in the registry:

```
2023-10-16 20:36:50 time="2023-10-16T18:36:50.38339359Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code="blob unknown" err.detail=sha256:2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0 err.message="blob unknown to registry" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=318083de-0085-40bd-8ffb-3878e5fca832 http.request.method=HEAD http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38954" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/sha256:2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration="550.042µs" http.response.status=404 http.response.written=157 vars.digest="sha256:2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0" vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" 
2023-10-16 20:36:50 time="2023-10-16T18:36:50.386371757Z" level=info msg="response completed" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/json" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=5505dd4d-28cd-46bb-8874-d45ce7c12abc http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38954" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/?from=quarkus%2Fubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image&mount=sha256%3A2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0&origin=quay.io" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.duration=2.009083ms http.response.status=202 http.response.written=0 
2023-10-16 20:36:58 time="2023-10-16T18:36:58.223126135Z" level=error msg="client disconnected during blob PATCH" contentLength=-1 copied=94845179 error="unexpected EOF" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=40d92a29-888d-4f48-8e9c-be9083bec49f http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38954" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/d2bec858-3305-478b-9718-6dea4605cab8?_state=yuPJBrufI-W6pGTluZyB8eQtXXWxfG9zyHWKTW8Bi3p7Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiZDJiZWM4NTgtMzMwNS00NzhiLTk3MTgtNmRlYTQ2MDVjYWI4IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM2OjUwLjM4NDY2NTc1N1oifQ%3D%3D" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" vars.uuid=d2bec858-3305-478b-9718-6dea4605cab8 
2023-10-16 20:36:58 time="2023-10-16T18:36:58.223130969Z" level=error msg="client disconnected during blob PATCH" contentLength=-1 copied=95836412 error="unexpected EOF" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=f1986cca-5075-4420-bec9-15732d6a75cf http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38982" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/9eb32ddb-cce3-413b-a725-af3d6f0f375d?_state=gmP4hcJx38JRRMnqQHdvZOmuqGmm2ZUtb9-6B_c4lBh7Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiOWViMzJkZGItY2NlMy00MTNiLWE3MjUtYWYzZDZmMGYzNzVkIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM2OjUwLjM1NTg5OTc1N1oifQ%3D%3D" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" vars.uuid=9eb32ddb-cce3-413b-a725-af3d6f0f375d 
2023-10-16 20:36:58 2023/10/16 18:36:58 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from github.com/docker/distribution/vendor/github.com/gorilla/handlers.(*responseLogger).WriteHeader (handlers.go:125)
2023-10-16 20:36:58 time="2023-10-16T18:36:58.348303635Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code=unknown err.detail="client disconnected" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=40d92a29-888d-4f48-8e9c-be9083bec49f http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38954" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/d2bec858-3305-478b-9718-6dea4605cab8?_state=yuPJBrufI-W6pGTluZyB8eQtXXWxfG9zyHWKTW8Bi3p7Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiZDJiZWM4NTgtMzMwNS00NzhiLTk3MTgtNmRlYTQ2MDVjYWI4IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM2OjUwLjM4NDY2NTc1N1oifQ%3D%3D" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=7.722810045s http.response.status=500 http.response.written=89 vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" vars.uuid=d2bec858-3305-478b-9718-6dea4605cab8 
2023-10-16 20:36:58 2023/10/16 18:36:58 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from github.com/docker/distribution/vendor/github.com/gorilla/handlers.(*responseLogger).WriteHeader (handlers.go:125)
2023-10-16 20:36:58 time="2023-10-16T18:36:58.349796427Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code=unknown err.detail="client disconnected" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=f1986cca-5075-4420-bec9-15732d6a75cf http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38982" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/9eb32ddb-cce3-413b-a725-af3d6f0f375d?_state=gmP4hcJx38JRRMnqQHdvZOmuqGmm2ZUtb9-6B_c4lBh7Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiOWViMzJkZGItY2NlMy00MTNiLWE3MjUtYWYzZDZmMGYzNzVkIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM2OjUwLjM1NTg5OTc1N1oifQ%3D%3D" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=7.70811292s http.response.status=500 http.response.written=89 vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" vars.uuid=9eb32ddb-cce3-413b-a725-af3d6f0f375d 
2023-10-16 20:37:01 time="2023-10-16T18:37:01.461811304Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code="blob unknown" err.detail=sha256:033a518c59b1941bd60b32260e5921289dd9cf57278be2fc86205ba24a86d2f7 err.message="blob unknown to registry" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=4ca08983-3736-4511-8ad2-1fa8c3eeb78b http.request.method=HEAD http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38966" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/sha256:033a518c59b1941bd60b32260e5921289dd9cf57278be2fc86205ba24a86d2f7" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration="712.667µs" http.response.status=404 http.response.written=157 vars.digest="sha256:033a518c59b1941bd60b32260e5921289dd9cf57278be2fc86205ba24a86d2f7" vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" 
2023-10-16 20:37:01 time="2023-10-16T18:37:01.466118054Z" level=info msg="response completed" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/json" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=3a364539-486b-4a4b-8d9d-ecfa2c671eab http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38966" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/?from=quarkus%2Fubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image&mount=sha256%3A033a518c59b1941bd60b32260e5921289dd9cf57278be2fc86205ba24a86d2f7&origin=quay.io" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.duration=2.8155ms http.response.status=202 http.response.written=0 
2023-10-16 20:36:50 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:18:36:50 +0000] "POST /v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/?from=quarkus%2Fubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image&mount=sha256%3A2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0&origin=quay.io HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "" "go-containerregistry/v0.15.2"
2023-10-16 20:36:58 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:18:36:50 +0000] "PATCH /v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/d2bec858-3305-478b-9718-6dea4605cab8?_state=yuPJBrufI-W6pGTluZyB8eQtXXWxfG9zyHWKTW8Bi3p7Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiZDJiZWM4NTgtMzMwNS00NzhiLTk3MTgtNmRlYTQ2MDVjYWI4IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM2OjUwLjM4NDY2NTc1N1oifQ%3D%3D HTTP/1.1" 500 89 "" "go-containerregistry/v0.15.2"
2023-10-16 20:36:58 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:18:36:50 +0000] "PATCH /v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/9eb32ddb-cce3-413b-a725-af3d6f0f375d?_state=gmP4hcJx38JRRMnqQHdvZOmuqGmm2ZUtb9-6B_c4lBh7Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiOWViMzJkZGItY2NlMy00MTNiLWE3MjUtYWYzZDZmMGYzNzVkIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM2OjUwLjM1NTg5OTc1N1oifQ%3D%3D HTTP/1.1" 500 89 "" "go-containerregistry/v0.15.2"
2023-10-16 20:37:01 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:18:37:01 +0000] "HEAD /v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/sha256:033a518c59b1941bd60b32260e5921289dd9cf57278be2fc86205ba24a86d2f7 HTTP/1.1" 404 157 "" "go-containerregistry/v0.15.2"
2023-10-16 20:37:01 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:18:37:01 +0000] "POST /v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/?from=quarkus%2Fubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image&mount=sha256%3A033a518c59b1941bd60b32260e5921289dd9cf57278be2fc86205ba24a86d2f7&origin=quay.io HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "" "go-containerregistry/v0.15.2"
2023-10-16 20:37:01 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:18:37:01 +0000] "HEAD /v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/sha256:2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0 HTTP/1.1" 404 157 "" "go-containerregistry/v0.15.2"
2023-10-16 20:37:01 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:18:37:01 +0000] "POST /v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/?from=quarkus%2Fubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image&mount=sha256%3A2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0&origin=quay.io HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "" "go-containerregistry/v0.15.2"
2023-10-16 20:37:04 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:18:37:01 +0000] "PATCH /v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/12169c01-a0b3-40a3-9e9b-9756cd40bff5?_state=XBpp5Z5kNkchBh79Fb5Jq4bjCyhGA7UqzjEYmaCCXON7Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiMTIxNjljMDEtYTBiMy00MGEzLTllOWItOTc1NmNkNDBiZmY1IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM3OjAxLjQ5MjUzNjU5NVoifQ%3D%3D HTTP/1.1" 500 89 "" "go-containerregistry/v0.15.2"
2023-10-16 20:37:04 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:18:37:01 +0000] "PATCH /v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/bac342b5-3835-4afd-b1d6-5829973a46e6?_state=Ap878ZQ5qyi8_yRu2LnsYb5G0c8S_ou9GgOJTMB7Qe17Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiYmFjMzQyYjUtMzgzNS00YWZkLWIxZDYtNTgyOTk3M2E0NmU2IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM3OjAxLjQ2NDI0MDIyWiJ9 HTTP/1.1" 500 89 "" "go-containerregistry/v0.15.2"
2023-10-16 20:37:01 time="2023-10-16T18:37:01.491152804Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code="blob unknown" err.detail=sha256:2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0 err.message="blob unknown to registry" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=fdb22a91-58f0-4a92-be9a-edb497887a8e http.request.method=HEAD http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38966" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/sha256:2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration="462.334µs" http.response.status=404 http.response.written=157 vars.digest="sha256:2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0" vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" 
2023-10-16 20:37:01 time="2023-10-16T18:37:01.494418429Z" level=info msg="response completed" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/json" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=99d1540a-35e3-4914-b35c-96a72adb2ab9 http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38966" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/?from=quarkus%2Fubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image&mount=sha256%3A2a69434d8218d8965f77253777157d8bfe0e583df183ff1944db2bcc991118c0&origin=quay.io" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.duration=2.25375ms http.response.status=202 http.response.written=0 
2023-10-16 20:37:04 time="2023-10-16T18:37:04.657270388Z" level=error msg="client disconnected during blob PATCH" contentLength=-1 copied=37112058 error="unexpected EOF" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=87794917-692e-4584-9d8e-37421e8b0dbc http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38966" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/12169c01-a0b3-40a3-9e9b-9756cd40bff5?_state=XBpp5Z5kNkchBh79Fb5Jq4bjCyhGA7UqzjEYmaCCXON7Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiMTIxNjljMDEtYTBiMy00MGEzLTllOWItOTc1NmNkNDBiZmY1IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM3OjAxLjQ5MjUzNjU5NVoifQ%3D%3D" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" vars.uuid=12169c01-a0b3-40a3-9e9b-9756cd40bff5 
2023-10-16 20:37:04 time="2023-10-16T18:37:04.66927268Z" level=error msg="client disconnected during blob PATCH" contentLength=-1 copied=35743994 error="unexpected EOF" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=df0b7111-72e0-4a8a-b68a-9c9fa034f282 http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:53652" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/bac342b5-3835-4afd-b1d6-5829973a46e6?_state=Ap878ZQ5qyi8_yRu2LnsYb5G0c8S_ou9GgOJTMB7Qe17Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiYmFjMzQyYjUtMzgzNS00YWZkLWIxZDYtNTgyOTk3M2E0NmU2IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM3OjAxLjQ2NDI0MDIyWiJ9" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" vars.uuid=bac342b5-3835-4afd-b1d6-5829973a46e6 
2023-10-16 20:37:04 2023/10/16 18:37:04 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from github.com/docker/distribution/vendor/github.com/gorilla/handlers.(*responseLogger).WriteHeader (handlers.go:125)
2023-10-16 20:37:04 time="2023-10-16T18:37:04.682105847Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code=unknown err.detail="client disconnected" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=87794917-692e-4584-9d8e-37421e8b0dbc http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:38966" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/12169c01-a0b3-40a3-9e9b-9756cd40bff5?_state=XBpp5Z5kNkchBh79Fb5Jq4bjCyhGA7UqzjEYmaCCXON7Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiMTIxNjljMDEtYTBiMy00MGEzLTllOWItOTc1NmNkNDBiZmY1IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM3OjAxLjQ5MjUzNjU5NVoifQ%3D%3D" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=2.947491377s http.response.status=500 http.response.written=89 vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" vars.uuid=12169c01-a0b3-40a3-9e9b-9756cd40bff5 
2023-10-16 20:37:04 2023/10/16 18:37:04 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from github.com/docker/distribution/vendor/github.com/gorilla/handlers.(*responseLogger).WriteHeader (handlers.go:125)
2023-10-16 20:37:04 time="2023-10-16T18:37:04.704886847Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code=unknown err.detail="client disconnected" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.20.8 http.request.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.request.host="host.docker.internal:5000" http.request.id=df0b7111-72e0-4a8a-b68a-9c9fa034f282 http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:53652" http.request.uri="/v2/default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder/blobs/uploads/bac342b5-3835-4afd-b1d6-5829973a46e6?_state=Ap878ZQ5qyi8_yRu2LnsYb5G0c8S_ou9GgOJTMB7Qe17Ik5hbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0L2NhbWVsLWstcnVudGltZS1xdWFya3VzLWJ1aWxkZXIiLCJVVUlEIjoiYmFjMzQyYjUtMzgzNS00YWZkLWIxZDYtNTgyOTk3M2E0NmU2IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTE2VDE4OjM3OjAxLjQ2NDI0MDIyWiJ9" http.request.useragent="go-containerregistry/v0.15.2" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=2.951186459s http.response.status=500 http.response.written=89 vars.name="default/camel-k-runtime-quarkus-builder" vars.uuid=bac342b5-3835-4afd-b1d6-5829973a46e6
```

Edit 2:
When I add the `--logs` parameter I receive the following output:

```
❯ kamel run myfirstintegration.kts --logs
Unable to retrieve the operator version: Get "https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api?timeout=32s": EOF
Error: Get "https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api?timeout=32s": EOF
```

Edit 3: Output of `docker version`

```
❯ docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.5
 Version:           24.0.6
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.7
 Git commit:        ed223bc
 Built:             Mon Sep  4 12:28:49 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.24.2 (124339)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.6
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.7
  Git commit:       1a79695
  Built:            Mon Sep  4 12:31:36 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.22
  GitCommit:        8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.8
  GitCommit:        v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: what is the output for kubectl get camelcatalog

Comment: Name: camel-catalog-2.16.0 
Runtime: quarkus
Runtime Camel: 3.20.1
Phase: Error

Comment: From the output, it looks like kamel depends on kubernetes and you don't have that running.

Comment: this was true yes. Now that I fixed Kubernetes again, I'm back at this "Reconciler error" which mentions that some "integration controller" is not running.... it's frustrating

Comment: Can you remove your camel-k installation and reinstall it and wait for camelcatalog to be ready after waiting for some time. And the start integration using --dev mode

Comment: tried with `kamel uninstall` and also removed image and containers. After that I installed it again like described for docker desktop but I can't get rid of the "helloworld" integration and thus I'm immediately running into the same error logs again.

Comment: tried again with `kamel uninstall --all` which worked better now. reinstallation was successful and I do not get the error logs immediately. I added also the `--example` parameter this time. And I have now a container running which produces log entries `Hello from Camel K`. Which is at least one step forward

Comment: @VigneshNayakManel now it works: i changed the install command to this `kamel install --registry host.docker.internal:5000 --registry-insecure true --log-level=debug --example --olm=false --save --wait
` maybe one of the additional parameters helped. Thx for your support. It's running now

Answer (score 0):

After I uninstalled via `kamel uninstall --all` and was sure nothing from Camel was left on my docker desktop instance, I installed kamel again via

```
kamel install --registry host.docker.internal:5000 --registry-insecure true --log-level=debug --example --olm=false --save --wait
```

Which lead to the result that I am now able to run my own integrations.